# Ace Editor HTML mode how enable automatically close brackets

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

i'm trying to enable the autocompletion to close automatically square brackets and curly braces in HTML but doesn't work, i have seen that the mode-html.js file contains the CstyleBehaviour, but seems that isn't activated, there is a way to activate it in HTML mode? i use ace editor also for php, and there work the auto close brackets works, and in mode-php.js there is the same CstyleBehaviour. Any help?

Comment: Maybe you just need to activate this option in editor, ```editor.setBehavioursEnabled(true)```.